# jTable in ASP.Net error in communicating with server

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, sql, jquery-jtable

I've been trying to get my jtable to work from aspx c# codes.. ASP.net I suppose.

But after messing it with days, I'm still unable to figure out where did I make a mistake that gives me this error when running the aspx.:

> An error occurred while communicating to the server.

Below is the script I have done. It is initiating the jtable and the list of actions that is needed to List, Create, Delete and Update.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Prepare jtable plugin
        $('#UserTableContainer').jtable({
            title: 'User Management System',
            paging: false,
            pageSize: 20,
            sorting: true,
            defaultSorting: 'userName',
            actions: {
                listAction: '/administrator/ADMUser.aspx/userList',
                createAction: '/administrator/ADMUser.aspx/userCreate',
                updateAction: '/administrator/ADMUser.aspx/userUpdate',
                deleteAction: '/administrator/ADMUser.aspx/userDelete'
            },
            fields: {
                userId: {
                    key: true,
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: false
                },
                userName: {
                    title: 'Username',
                    width: '23%',
                    create: true,
                    edit: false,
                    list: true
                },
                userFullname: {
                    title: 'Full Name',
                    width: '23%',
                    create: true,
                    edit: true,
                    list: true
                },
                userEmail: {
                    title: 'Email address',
                    list: true,
                    create: true,
                    edit: true
                },
                userPassword: {
                    title: 'User Password',
                    type: 'password',
                    list: false,
                    edit: true,
                    create: true
                },
                CreatedDate: {
                    title: 'Date Created',
                    width: '15%',
                    type: 'date',
                    create: false,
                    edit: false,
                    list: true,
                    displayFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                },
                userRole: {
                    title: 'User Roles',
                    width: '15%',
                    create: true,
                    edit: true,
                    list: true,
                    options: '/Administrator/ADMMembersManagement.aspx/GetUserRoles',
                    sorting: false
                }
            }
        });

        $('#UserTableContainer').jtable('load');
    });
</script>
```

Then, the next is the ASPX.CS codes that has the methods.

Do note, I placed the getUserList method in the UserManager as returning a  of User Objects.   Not sure if i'm right, but i've seen some people tried doing it with stored procedures in SQL. However, I'm unsure with Stored procedures but I've done it in normal SQL query commands.

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static object userList(int jtStartIndex = 0, int jtPageSize = 0, string jtSorting = null)
    {
        try
        {
            UserManager um = new UserManager();
            //Get data from database
            List<TemplateUser> students = um.getUserList(jtStartIndex, jtPageSize, jtSorting);
            int memberCount = um.TotalNumberOfUsers;

            //Return result to jTable
            return new { Result = "OK", Records = students, TotalRecordCount = memberCount };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return new { Result = "ERROR", Message = ex.Message + "REALLY HERE" };
        }

    }
```

And then lastly, my UserManager code, which I have my getUserList method stored in.

```
 public List<TemplateUser> getUserList(int inStartIndex, int inPageSize, string inSort)
    {
        List<TemplateUser> userList = new List<TemplateUser>();
        TemplateUser user;
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();

        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WEBA_Assignment"].ConnectionString;
        con.ConnectionString = connString;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY userName ASC) AS Row, * FROM Users) AS StudentsWithRowNumbers WHERE Row > @inStarIndex AND Row <= @inPageSize ";
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@inStartIndex", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@inStartIndex"].Value = inStartIndex;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@inPageSize", SqlDbType.Int);
        cmd.Parameters["@inPageSize"].Value = inPageSize;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        con.Open(); 
        da.Fill(ds, "UserData");
        con.Close();
        foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables["UserData"].Rows)
        {
            user = new TemplateUser();
            user.userId = int.Parse(dr["userId"].ToString());
            user.userName = dr["userName"].ToString();
            user.userPassword = dr["userPassword"].ToString();
            user.userFullname = dr["userFullname"].ToString();
            user.userEmail = dr["userEmail"].ToString();
            user.ActivationStatus = int.Parse(dr["ActivationStatus"].ToString());
            user.userRole = int.Parse(dr["userRole"].ToString());


            int year; int month; int day; int hour; int minute; int second;
            year = ((DateTime)dr["CreatedDate"]).Year;
            month = ((DateTime)dr["CreatedDate"]).Month;
            day = ((DateTime)dr["CreatedDate"]).Day;
            hour = ((DateTime)dr["CreatedDate"]).Hour;
            minute = ((DateTime)dr["CreatedDate"]).Minute;
            second = ((DateTime)dr["CreatedDate"]).Second;

            user.CreatedDate = new DateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);
            cmd.CommandText = "Select Count(*) 'NumOfRows' FROM Users";
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            con.Open();
            da.Fill(ds, "NumOfRows");
            con.Close();
            TotalNumberOfUsers = int.Parse(dr["NumOfRows"].ToString());
            userList.Add(user);
        }
        return userList;
    }//getUserList
```

I'm really troubled with this issue, cause I'm unsure where to continue from here on. Initially I didn't have the Startindex and Paging done for the jtable, but I've seen some other user's question which has answers that it's necessary which then I placed them in.

But still... no results...